# light Intensity and its effects on energy and emitted electron on metal surface

Tags: spectroscopy, photochemistry

we have a metal surface with electrons in a specific energy state say X ,now we shine light on it of specific wavelength and intensity.
now what if i double the intensity of light , what would happen to the number of electrons emitted and the average energy of the electrons ?

my guess is that since intensity is doubled, then number of photons emitted also double and the energy also doubles .... but i am not really sure about it

Answer (score 1):

> what if i double the intensity of light , what would happen to the
>   number of electrons emitted and the average energy of the electrons?

This is known as the "Photoelectric Effect" and is described by the following equation

$$\ce{E_{max}=h\nu- WF_{M}}$$

where $\ce{E_{max}}$ is the maximum kinetic energy of the electron escaping from the metal surface, $\nu$ is the frequency of the incoming photon and $\ce{WF_{M}}$ is the workfunction for the particular metal. Your guess is part right, doubling the intensity of the incoming beam doubles the number of electrons ejected from the metal surface, but their kinetic energy distribution remains unchanged.  The maximum kinetic energy of an emitted electron is still determined by the above equation and therefor still capped by $\ce{E_{max}}$ and the kinetic energies of all electrons emitted are still distributed from 0 to $\ce{E_{max}}$.  If you'd like more information, [here's a good, concise reference](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Physical_Chemistry/Quantum_Mechanics/Quantum_States_of_Atoms_and_Molecules/2._Foundations_of_Quantum_Mechanics/Photoelectric_Effect).

Answer (score 0):

The intensity of emitted light varies directly with the number of photoelectrons emitted. If the intensity of light is varied, keeping the frequency of the source and the accelerating potential constant, the resulting photo-current produced is found to increase,i.e. the photo-current vs intensity of incident light curve is linear having a constant slope. Since the number of photoelectrons emitted per second is directly proportional to photo current produced, therefore it is also **proportional to the intensity of incident light.**

> The above equation that has been stated in the previous answer can also be written as:

E(max)=eV, where e is the basic electronic charge and V represents the stopping potential. Now it has been found that the stopping potential is dependent on the frequency of incident light and is independent of its intensity. This implies that the **maximum kinetic energy of emitted photo-electrons is independent of intensity** too[since, it remains proportional to stooping potential].